# Replaced toilet tank only now toilet wont't flush /empty bowl

Tags: toilet

I had a cracked tank dripping water. We replaced it with a new tank that had all hardware already inside. After installing the new tank tried to flush toilet and the water drains from tank but doesn't actually flush/empty bowl.
Tank refills each time. It only emptied the bowl once. Any suggestions?
We tried adjust the chain on the arm to different levels and still no success.

Comment: Sound like you need to raise the water level in the tank. There is an *overflow tube* in the tank; how close is the water level, when full, to the top of the overflow tube?

Comment: Can your edit your post and insert a picture of the inside of your new tank, with the water full?

Comment: Just making sure, the new tank is the same size/type as the old tank?

Comment: we adjusted water level higher and tension on arm and have gotten more success, the tank is slightly larger than old tank but not by much.

Comment: If it's larger volume but wider and shorter, that can be a problem. A taller tank provides more pressure for the flush than a shorter tank does. Recent low-flush toilets tend to have a tall, narrow tank for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

The bowl does not flush because there is not enough water discharged when you push the flush handle or button.

There should be a mark on the inside of the tank to indicate the "Approximate" proper water level.  If not, shoot for about an inch below the overflow tube.

If you get a "double flush", adjust the level a bit lower until you get the proper flush.